# Firebase FirebaseRecyclerAdaptor from Firebase-UI not returnig data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using the `FirebaseRecyclerAdaptor` but not getting the data from the database.

First I create a Query:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("items");
```

Then I build the `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` object but when I log the Options Snapshot, I get a null or an empty array.

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Item> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Item>()
                        .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<Item>() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Item parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                return snapshot.getValue(Item.class);
                            }
                        })
                        .build();
    Log.e("Ref", String.valueOf(options.getSnapshots()));
```

I then initialize my adaptor:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, ItemsViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Item model) {
                holder.tv_item_price.setText(Integer.toString(model.getItemPrice()));
                holder.tv_item_description.setText(model.getItemDescription());
                holder.tv_item_name.setText(model.getItemName());

                Picasso.with(getContext())
                        .load(model.getImage())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                        .into(holder.img_image);

                holder.btn_select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int total = Integer.parseInt(((MainActivity)getActivity()).cart_price.getText().toString()) + model.getItemPrice();
                        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).cart_price.setText(Integer.toString(total));

                        selectedItems.add(model);

                        Log.e("00", Integer.toString(selectedItems.size()));
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ItemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.single_item_view, parent, false);

                return new ItemsViewHolder(view);
            }

        };

adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Why am i getting the snapshots as an empty array?

**Note that when i use the " addValueEventListener " it works well**

```
//        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//                items.clear();
//
//                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
//                    Item newItem = snapshot.getValue(Item.class);
//                    items.add(newItem);
//                    Log.i("Mysnapshot", snapshot.toString());
//
//                }
//
//                    adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
//
//            }
//        });
```

[image: Check out the error Log]

> My Firebase Database Structure is as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuSaK.png)
>
> My Java Class is shown below........

```
public class Item implements Parcelable {
        private String itemName;
        private String itemDescription;
        private String itemUid;
        private int itemPrice;
        private int itemCount;
        private String image;

        public Item() {}  // Needed for Firebase

        public Item(String itemName, String itemDescription, String itemUid, int itemPrice, int itemCount, String image) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
            this.itemUid = itemUid;
            this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
            this.itemCount = itemCount;
            this.image = image;
        }

        protected Item(Parcel in) {
            itemName = in.readString();
            itemDescription = in.readString();
            itemUid = in.readString();
            itemPrice = in.readInt();
            itemCount = in.readInt();
            image = in.readString();
        }

        public static final Creator<Item> CREATOR = new Creator<Item>() {
            @Override
            public Item createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Item(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Item[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Item[size];
            }
        };

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }

        public void setItemName(String itemName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }

        public String getItemDescription() {
            return itemDescription;
        }

        public void setItemDescription(String itemDescription) {
            this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
        }

        public String getItemUid() {
            return itemUid;
        }

        public void setItemUid(String itemUid) {
            this.itemUid = itemUid;
        }

        public int getItemPrice() {
            return itemPrice;
        }

        public void setItemPrice(int itemPrice) {
            this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        }

        public int getItemCount() {
            return itemCount;
        }

        public void setItemCount(int itemCount) {
            this.itemCount = itemCount;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(itemName);
            dest.writeString(itemDescription);
            dest.writeString(itemUid);
            dest.writeInt(itemPrice);
            dest.writeInt(itemCount);
            dest.writeString(image);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: Should i filter to errors or something?

Comment: Yes, only that one can read the error

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/63wTQ.png

Comment: can you show us Item.class and your database structure ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` but you aren't listening for changes. To solve this, please add the following lines of code, in your `onStart()` and onStop() methods, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

This is a quite common mistake that developers do because in the earlier versions, this practice was not needed.

Comment: I doesn't work, ok but what is the bahaviour? Do you have an error? Please also share the content of your `Item` class.

Comment: we need the database structure from OP and see if maybe the variables from item.class are different than the ones in the database

Comment: As Gastón asked you, please show us the content of yout `Item` class, ok?

Comment: Hello everyone, i am grateful for your concern. i Just provided the Pojo and the Image for the DB Structure.

Comment: You have in your logcat as the last line this: `[]`. From which log statement comes?

Comment: Alex. i got the solution to this at last i used a different approach. Though this official documentation from google i managed without changing the Pojo. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database/realtime/RealtimeDbChatActivity.java

Comment: A different approach which is?

Comment: I still don't understand why my first approach didn't work, but thanks to all